# When installing TestLink 1.9.20 I get an error message when trying to connect to the database

Tags: testlink

I downloaded the installation pack for TestLink from SourceForge, and I attempted to install it on the server.
When the installation is trying to connect to the database, I get this message:

```
TestLink setup will now attempt to setup the database:

Creating connection to Database Server:OK!


Connecting to database `testlink`:OK!

 ============================================================================== 

 DB Access Error - debug_print_backtrace() OUTPUT START 

 ATTENTION: Enabling more debug info will produce path disclosure weakness (CWE-200) 

            Having this additional Information could be useful for reporting 

            issue to development TEAM. 

 ============================================================================== 

#0  database->exec_query() called at [/home/galigeo/testlink/install/installUtils.php:100]
#1  getUserList() called at [/home/galigeo/testlink/install/installUtils.php:267]
#2  create_user_for_db() called at [/home/galigeo/testlink/install/installNewDB.php:420]
```

Does anybody know how I should proceed from here?
We also tried to download another pack for `1.9.20` from Github, however that one is also stalling.

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem like you and fixed like this:

1. Access link like https://yourtestlink.com/install
2. Done anything in these step.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).